# Strip tags after entering it into an array?

Tags: php

How can I strip the tags of the individual item? Using the current setup I end up with one long string that all the tags have been stripped.

How can I enter the `$title` into the `$value` array then strip the tags for it?

```
// Product Codes
$contents = $html->find('div[class=product-table]', 0);
$contents = $contents->find('tr');
$counter = 1;
$value = array();
foreach ($contents as $item) {
  $field_key = "field_5ae0882f9d6f9";
  $title = strip_tags($item);
  $value[] = array(
    "column_title" => $title,
  );
  $counter++;
  break;
}
update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id );
```

This is the original table, I want to add each table title as an individual item, strip the tags, then use then `update_field` function to push them into Wordpress via the Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

[image]

Comment: What is `$item`? What does `$value` come out as/

Comment: @user3783243 `$item` contains individual titles (with some html that I want to strip). The current setup just outputs `$value` as one long string with all tags stripped instead of individual items with the tags stripped.

Comment: What is the expected output? Do you want to split on columns? `$contents = $contents->find('tr td');` might do the trick

Comment: What is the problem here? What does **not** with your code?

Comment: change to foreach($contents->find('td') as $item)

Comment: @SanderBackus Is it possible to find the first `tr` then all it's `td's`?

Comment: @Rob If that's issue see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246490/parse-html-using-php-and-loop-through-table-rows-and-columns

Comment: Not sure what kind of library you're using but I would expect `$tr = $contents->find('tr'); foreach($tr as $trx) { $tds = $trx->find('td'); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what your looking for?

```
// Product Codes
$contents = $html->find('div[class=product-table]', 0);
$contents = $contents->find('tr', 0)->find('td');
$counter = 1;
$value = array();
foreach ($contents as $item) {
  $field_key = "field_5ae0882f9d6f9";
  $value[] = array(
    "column_title" => "<td>" . strip_tags($item) . "</td>",
  );
  $counter++;
}
var_dump($value);
update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id );
```

Comment: You just made `$title` undefined. That wont help

Comment: @MatthewGoheen Not quite, it's outputting each row as one string (I changed `$title` to `$item`). I want to find the first `tr` then add each individual `td` with it's tags stripped.

Comment: I'm having trouble imagining whats going on. would you be able to post a working example of whats happening?

Comment: @MatthewGoheen I've updated my question with more info and a screenshot (it's difficult to get a working version going).

Comment: It would be easier to work out with a working example. Did any of the changes I made help?

Comment: @MatthewGoheen That outputs `<tr>        Patient Weight (Kg)  Size   Max ET Tube ID (mm)   Max Suction Catheter (Fr)  Pack Size  </tr>`. I want each one of those titles to be an individual item, at the moment it's one long string. Stripping the tags seems to stop them being individual items.

Comment: @Rob What happens if we change the `tr` tags to `td` tags?

Comment: @MatthewGoheen That's very close! I just want the `td's` in the first row. It's outputting every `td` in every row as an individual item... so very close. Sorry you're doing this "blind"!

Comment: @Rob Maybe like that then?

Comment: @MatthewGoheen Just put in the same fix myself... yes, it works! Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 0):

```
// Product Codes
$contents = $html->find('div[class=product-table]', 0);
$contents = $contents->find('tr');
$counter = 1;
$value = array();
$i=0;

foreach ($contents as $tr) {
    if($i==0){
        foreach($tr->find('td') as $item) {
            $field_key = "field_5ae0882f9d6f9";
            $title = strip_tags($item);
            $value[] = array(
                 "column_title" => $title,
            );
            $counter++;
        }
    }
    $i++;

}
update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id );
```

Changed it to iterate through tr's, limited to one.  Should iterate through all the td's of that row.

Comment: That would only hit the first `td` then break.

Comment: Took the break out.